# Set width of input field to width of original content (with CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement the following feature:
A webpage with many lines such as
`Type.classname=com.long.qualified.class.Name`, where the line corresponds to an entry in a Java properties file.  Each such line references a file named (contextRoot)/.../path/.../Name.java.

I want to be able to copy the filename easily, so I can (in Eclipse) locate the source file referenced by the property.  So, I'm making the package name a `<label>` and the class name an `<input>`, connecting them with a `for`.  Then I added an `onfocus` to the class name, in which I do `this.select()`.  I also added styling to make the text field not look like a text field, i.e. font, border:none, readonly (not CSS).

My first question is: how do I set the width of the text field to the full width of it's *original* content.  Other questions had answers about adjusting the width dynamically - this is not an issue for me.  Can it be done with CSS, or do I have to use javascript.  There are over 1000 such lines, and I'd rather not use more script than I need to.

My second question is: am I doing these the hard way, and there's an easier way to accomplish my goal, or is this pretty much the way anyone else would do it?

Thanks.

Comment: CSS cannot compare values. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I used a jQuery .each() to set the size to the length of the text (+2 for good luck...).  Doesn't seem to add that much to the page loading time, most of that is on the server (>5 seconds), but the file is 250KB, generated from a JSP. Oh, well.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the box-sizing property to achieve what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/AjtCR/

Here's what browsers it's compatible with: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

```
​<div>
 <input type="text" />
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​div {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:#999;
 padding-top:50px;
}

input {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width:100%;
 padding:5px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to accomplish what I'm trying to do.  I wanted to set a textbox size to at least the width of its value, up to the end of the page.  I just adjusted the size with js, and that seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, must have misunderstood your requirements.